# How to format and align the text using vim, sed or awk command?

Tags: vim, awk, sed, terraform

I'm trying to align the file content for my convenient. All the scattered variables to be in a single line. Also the smallest variable name in the first order. Could someone please help me to achieve this using sed, awk or VIM editor?

**Actual file content**

```
variable "key_name" {
  default = ""
}

variable "vpc_id" {
  default = ""
}

variable "name" {
  default = ""
}

variable "ami" {
  default = ""
}

variable "instance_type" {
  default = ""
}

variable "name_suffix" {
  default = ""
}

variable "additional_volume_size" {
  default = ""
}
```

**Expected output**

```
variable "ami"                        { default = "" }
variable "name"                       { default = "" }
variable "vpc_id"                     { default = "" }
variable "key_name"                   { default = "" }
variable "name_suffix"                { default = "" }
variable "instance_type"              { default = "" }
variable "additional_volume_size"     { default = "" }
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk` and `column`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";OFS=" "}{$1=$1}1' file  | column -t
```

Output:

```
variable  "key_name"                {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "vpc_id"                  {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "name"                    {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "ami"                     {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "instance_type"           {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "name_suffix"             {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "additional_volume_size"  {  default  =  ""  }
```

---

If you want to sort the output by the length of the variable names you can output the length with `awk`, pipe to sort and remove the length afterwards, like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";OFS=" "}{$1=length($2)" "$1}1' file \
  | sort -k1,1n \
  | cut -d' ' -f2- \
  | column -t
```

Output:

```
variable  "ami"                     {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "name"                    {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "vpc_id"                  {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "key_name"                {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "name_suffix"             {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "instance_type"           {  default  =  ""  }
variable  "additional_volume_size"  {  default  =  ""  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response. Is there a way to sort the variable names from small to large?

Comment: that would be hard to achieve, but doable

Comment: Any hint on that? So that i can go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: let me think about it

Comment: You can use this: `awk 'BEGIN{RS="";OFS=" "}{$0=length($2)" "$0;$1=$1}1' file | sort -k1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2- | column -t`

Comment: You can do it directly within `vi` by pressing `ggVG!` followed by all the `awk` and `cut` stuff (with the filename omitted).

Comment: Why would you want to do it in `vi`?

Comment: @hek2mgl this works perfectly...

Comment: glad to hear that!